# form_load issue with updating details using session variables and textboxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to allow users to update their details after logging in on an asp site using vb. Textboxes are populated with user details using session variables in the form_load. The textboxes should be editable but for some reason are not registering the changes when the submit button is clicked.

There is a similar question with the same issue [Database not updating after UPDATE SQL statement in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467204/database-not-updating-after-update-sql-statement-in-asp-net) that was never answered.

Please can someone advise

Thanks in advance

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Txt_Fname.Text = Session("First_Name")
    Txt_LName.Text = Session("Last_Name")
    Txt_ContactNumber.Text = Session("Cell_Number")
    Txt_Email.Text = Session("Email_Address")
End Sub

Protected Sub Cmd_Submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cmd_Submit.Click



    Command.Connection = Connection
    Command.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.User_Account Set First_Name = @First_Name, Last_Name = @Last_Name, Cell_Number = @Cell_Number, Email_Address = @Email_Address where Overall_ID = @Overall_ID"
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", Txt_Fname.Text)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Txt_LName.Text)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell_Number", Txt_ContactNumber.Text)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_Address", Txt_Email.Text)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Overall_ID", Session("ID"))

    Connection.Open()
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Connection.Close()

    Response.Redirect("MyAccount.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: can you show us the code in the submit button?

Comment: without code it's going to be impossible to answer.  Questions include: at what point do you fill the textboxes? Are you checking to see if a postback occurred before filling them?  Have you put a break point to ensure your update statement is being called? etc.

Comment: That question has been answered. Please provide further details or close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add if not page.ispostback before your code in page_load.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) then
        Txt_Fname.Text = Session("First_Name")
        Txt_LName.Text = Session("Last_Name")
        Txt_ContactNumber.Text = Session("Cell_Number")
        Txt_Email.Text = Session("Email_Address")
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but it would help to post the code snippet to make it clear.